# find command with newer option does not work at milliseconds level

Tags: bash, find, solaris, sunos

I have created 3 files in SunOS, 2 of which have creation time varying in milliseconds. The 3rd file varying by a second. `find <path> -newer` does not seem to take milliseconds into consideration.

```
bash-3.2$ touch -d 2012-11-20T12:59:00.1234 /tmp/abc.txt    
bash-3.2$ touch -d 2012-11-20T12:59:00.4567 /tmp/abc1.txt    
bash-3.2$ touch -d 2012-11-20T12:59:01.0000 /tmp/abc2.txt    
bash-3.2$ ls -lE /tmp/abc*    
-rw-r--r--   1 blahuser  root            0 2012-11-20 12:59:00.123400000 +0100 /tmp/abc.txt    
-rw-r--r--   1 blahuser  root            0 2012-11-20 12:59:00.456700000 +0100 /tmp/abc1.txt    
-rw-r--r--   1 blahuser  root            0 2012-11-20 12:59:01.000000000 +0100 /tmp/abc2.txt
```

Here `find /tmp -newer /tmp/abc.txt` should have ideally displayed both */tmp/abc1.txt* and */tmp/abc2.txt* but actually it outputs only */tmp/abc2.txt*

```
bash-3.2$ find /tmp -type f -newer /tmp/abc.txt
/tmp/abc2.txt
```

Is there any other option for `find` which also takes milliseconds into consideration?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the answer is no.

Even the GNU find release bundled with Solaris only take account integer seconds.

You need to use custom code to manage the files modified in the same second than the reference one.

Comment: Might be good to note that this limitation in most `find` implementations may stem from the fact that traditionally, filesystems only record the timestamp to the nearest second.  I believe this is the case with ext2/ext3, UFS and others.  NTFS stores millisecond, but Windows boxes don't keep good time anyway, so it doesn't really matter.  If portability is important, find another place to store "< 1s" times.

Comment: @ghoti: At least UFS, ext2/ext3 and ZFS do record millisecond timestamps. GNU find on Linux does take them into account while Solaris GNU find does not.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I searched but apparently not long enough.  I see that Linux `ls` includes a `--full-time` option that shows the microtime. Now I need to find a way to display it in FreeBSD.  :/